# Can creditors force sale of shares to pay debt?

Tags: united-kingdom, debt

Can creditors force us to sell our shares in order to pay or reduce debts owed or perhaps put a court order in place in order that we use any income from them to reduce any debt? (We are in the process of applying for an [IVA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Individual_Voluntary_Arrangement)).

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: tagging as united-kingdom, based on the reference to the IVA.

Answer (score 2):

What creditors do is to get a "freeze" order on your accounts (to the amount that you owe.) That is, they place their claims for "first dibs" on your bank account, brokerage account, wages, etc. They won't force you to sell shares. But when you do sell them, you will have to pay the creditors first if they have the freeze in place.